# Where placed ioc.php file in the folder structure of Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, ioc-container

in my laravel 4.2 projects I use the file [ioc.php](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc), to use functions anywhere in my application:

```
Laravel 4.2 structure
|
|
|app|
    |routes.php
    |ioc.php <-- place here
```

**My ioc.php content:**

```
<?php
// services class
App::singleton('ApiRpService', function()
{
   $config = Config::get('app.web_config.api');
   $config['lang'] = Config::get('app.locale');
   $config['currency'] = Config::get('app.currency');
   $service = new \services\ApiService();
   $service -> configure(array_merge($config,Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]));   
   return $service;
});

App::singleton('CartService', function()
{
  //die(Config::get('app.web_config.webs.mantaspersonalizadas.es.local'));
   $service = new \services\CartService(App::make('ApiRpService'));
   return $service;
});

App::singleton('ApiCcService',function(){
    $api_cc =  new \services\ApiCcService(Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['secret_key_old_cc']);
    return $api_cc;
});

// shared cart when head render
View::composer('layouts.header', function($view)
{
    $cart_service = App::make('CartService');   

    $params = array();
    $params['cart'] = $cart_service->getCart();     

    //Controller::call('PagesController@getPromotionData');
    App::make('PagesController')->getPromotionData();
    # lenguajes extras
    $params['extra_langs'] = [];    
    $extra_langs = array_merge(@Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['lng_extra'],array(@Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['lng_default']));

    if (count($extra_langs) > 0){
        foreach($extra_langs as $lang)
        {
            if ($lang != App::getLocale())
            {
                $route_name = substr(Route::currentRouteName(), 0, strrpos(Route::currentRouteName(),'_')).'_'.$lang;
                //die(URL::route($route_name));
                $params['extra_langs'][] = array(
                    'lang' => $lang,
                    'url' =>  URL::route($route_name,array('--',Input::get('id','')))
                );
            }
        }           
    }
    $params['web_url'] = Request::root() . (strlen(Request::segment(1)) == 2? '/'.Request::segment(1):'');
    //dd($params['promotion_data']);
    $view -> with($params);
});

View::composer('layouts.head', function($view)
{
    if (App::environment('production'))
        $view -> with('g_analytics_id', @Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['g_analytics']['account']);    
});


View::composer('layouts.metas', function($view)
{
    $params = [];

    if (Lang::has('messages.welcome'))
        $params['title'] ="";

    if (Lang::has('messages.welcome'))
        $params['description'] ="";

    $view -> with($params);     
});

// shared newsletter when footer render
View::composer('layouts.footer', function($view)
{
    $api = App::make('ApiRpService');
    $view -> with(array(
        'token'       => $api->getPublicToken(),
        'google_plus' => @Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['google_plus'],
        'facebook'    => @Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['facebook'],
        'twitter'    => @Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['twitter'],
        'chat_online'    => @Config::get('app.web_config.webs')[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']]['chat_online']
    ));

});

App::singleton('imghelper', function(){
   return new \utils\ImageHelper(Config::get('app.web_config.urlStaticProductsImg'));
});
```

In Laravel 5 docs not mention the ioc.php...

Where I can place these functions?

Note that these functions are used in all views.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your individual services should have their own [ServiceProvder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers). These can be placed in any particular directory, and you can register all your service providers in your `config/app.php` to be automatically loaded and run.

You'll see in your `config/app.php` that a base Laravel project pre-registers some providers for your commonly used facades like `DB`.

Just make sure that the names of your service providers follow the [PSR-4 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) so that Laravel's auto-loader can correctly resolve the class!

If you're looking for the docs on "IOC" in Laravel 5, it is now called the "Service Container" - [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container) are the docs.

Comment: I do not understand you. The Providers are class files... I have only a few functions in my ioc.php. How would you do it? I have little time using Laravel.